# AWS Image Builder SSM execution error when cURLing s3 through an HTTP proxy - is there a way to inject the HTTP_PROXY env vars into image builder?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I believe that all i'd need to do to resolve this is to set SSM inside of Image Builder to use my proxy with the environment variable -> `HTTP_PROXY = HOST:IP`

for example, I can run this on another server where all traffic is directed through the proxy:
`curl -I --socks5-hostname socks.local:1080 https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip -o awscli-bundle.zip`

Here's what Image builder is trying to do and failing (before any of the image builder `components` are ran):

`SSM execution '68711005-5dc4-41f6-8cdd-633728ca41da' failed with status = 'Failed' in state = 'BUILDING' and failure message = 'Step fails when it is verifying the command has completed. Command 76b55646-79bb-417c-8bb6-6ee01f9a76ff returns unexpected invocation result: {Status=[Failed], ResponseCode=[7], Output=[ ----------ERROR------- + sudo systemctl stop ecs + curl https://s3.amazonaws.com/aws-cli/awscli-bundle.zip -o /tmp/imagebuilder_service/awscli-bundle.zip % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:01 --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:02 --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:03 --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:04 --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 --:--:-- 0:00:05 --:--:-- 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...'`

These env vars are all that should be needed, the problem is that i see no way to add them (similarly to how you would in CodeBuild):

```
http_proxy=http://hostname:port
https_proxy=https://hostname:port
no_proxy=169.254.169.254
```

Answer (score 0):

SSM Agent does not read environment variables from host, you would need to provide the environment variables in the file below and restart ssm agent

- On Ubuntu Server instances where SSM Agent is installed by using a snap: `/etc/systemd/system/snap.amazon-ssm-agent.amazon-ssm-agent.service.d/override.conf`
- On Amazon Linux 2 instances: `/etc/systemd/system/amazon-ssm-agent.service.d/override.conf`
- On other operating systems: `/etc/systemd/system/amazon-ssm-agent.service.d/amazon-ssm-agent.override`

```
[Service]
Environment="http_proxy=http://hostname:port"
Environment="https_proxy=https://hostname:port"
Environment="no_proxy=169.254.169.254"
```

Reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/sysman-proxy-with-ssm-agent.html#ssm-agent-proxy-systemd